# The 'charCode' property of a keydown event should not be used. The value is meaningless

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

What is the straight JavaScript syntax to replace the jQuery's `keydown` event?
Lint is complaining so much that it's hard to read my Firebug console.

Since I'm developing a proof-of-concept for me only, I'm not worried about any cross browser problems - it only has to work in Firefox at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "The 'charCode' property of a keydown event should not be used. The value is meaningless" error in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639055/getting-the-charcode-property-of-a-keydown-event-should-not-be-used-the-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$(document).keydown(function(myEvent) {
```

to

```
document.onkeydown=function(myEvent){
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because charCode is indeed meaningless in the keydown event. Change the keydown event to a keypress event if you need to know the charCode.

Comment: Changing it to keypress made the program stop working.  Does keypress return different values than keydown?

Comment: Yes, keydown tells you which key is pressed (eg. Shift, then 4), and keypress tells you which character was entered (eg. a dollar sign). That is why charCode is meaningless in the keydown event. See demos at [api.jquery.com/keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and [api.jquery.com/keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

Answer (score 2):

According to [DOM level2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-keyevents):

> The DOM Level 2 Event specification
>   does not provide a key event module.
>   An event module designed for use with
>   keyboard input devices will be
>   included in a later version of the DOM
>   specification.

So there is no standard concerning the key events. Currently all the browsers do as they see fit. If you are using a JS framework it should give a consistent value in all browsers (that would be the main point of the framework after all).

Comment: I don't get it.  What's the syntax for doing a keydown in Firefox only?

Comment: Check the compatibility tables again. The Yes/No lines usually start with a "Theory" and tell if that certain functionality is available on the tested browsers.

Answer (score 2):

First, the others explained quite well the roots of your problem.

But for the record, answering your original question, what you need is [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). This is a non-obtrusive, nice and modern way to attach events in Javascript. Works in every modern browser (so not under IE9, for those IEs you need [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So for example, using addEventListener, you assign events like:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("fos");
elem.addEventListener("keydown", whateverFunction, false);
```

You can also use the simple way (`elem.onkeydown=whateverFunction;`), but I discourage you to do it. With addEventListener, you can assign several handlers to the same event, and you cannot accidentally overwrite another event you or a library/3rd party script assigned.