# Regex is confusing me and why won't it parse properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Sorry about the confusing title. I'm new to Regex and JS/JQ in general. However, I'm trying to parse this. Basically, I want it to add the key pressed to the HTML if and ONLY if the keys 0-9 and the keys +, -, /, and * are pressed. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
function charCode(code) {
    return String.fromCharCode(code);
}

function escapeChars(esc) {
    return esc.replace(/[0-9\+-\*\/]*$/, "");
}

$('#tb').html("0");
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {

    var div = $('#tb');
    var which = event.which;
    which = charCode(which);
    which = escapeChars(which);
    else if (div.html() == "0") {
        //alert("Div is equal to 0."); --Debug
        div.html(which);
    } else {
        //alert("Div is equal to " + div.html()); --Debug
        div.html(div.html() + which);
    }
});
```

Currently, it doesn't allow anything through.

Comment: You're doing the opposite though, you're replacing everything that _is_ one of these to empty string.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum And how do I fix it exactly?

Comment: Negate the list inside `[]` prepending its content with `^`: `[0-9\+-*\/]`

Comment: You've got a syntax error: `else if` without a preceding `if` - just a typo in the question, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yup. Just a typo. I was in the process of removing another if statement when I posted this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your regular expression.

1. You want to replace characters that **do not** match your list. To do that, you start your character class (`[]`) with  a `^`.
2. You don't need to escape `+` or `*` in the regular expression. You do need to move the `-` to the beginning or end though.
3. You don't need the `*` or the `$` after the character class. Dropping those, you'll replace any character that doesn't match, no matter where it occurs in the string.
4. In case your string contains more than one character (may not apply here), adding a `g` flag to the end will allow you to replace *all* characters that do not match.

That results in a regular expression that looks like this:

```js
/[^0-9+*\/-]/g
```

This fiddle shows the above regular expression working: http://jsfiddle.net/WyttT/

### Updated

Another problem you're encountering is caused by checking keycodes from a `keydown` event. The keycodes on `keydown` [do not match to actual ascii character codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639055/getting-the-charcode-property-of-a-keydown-event-should-not-be-used-the-valu), so non-alphanumeric keys are getting converted into weird characters. If you change your even handler to respond to`keypress` instead, you'll get better results.

Comment: This works, but only with the numbers. +, *, - and / dont work.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't let the special characters that I want through.

Comment: @VinPix I've updated my answer to address this. A working version based off of your fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vRvGy/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want a regex for this. I think charAt() will do what you want far more simply.

You have a character. You have a list of characters which either match it or don't. charAt() does that simply and efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Now that jcsanyi has helped you with the regex, here is a simplification of your JS code. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/SpenserJ/pen/KioIn)

You will want to use keypress instead of keydown/keyup, otherwise your numpad will return the wrong keys, and anything requiring a shift (`shift+8` = `*` for instance) won't work. You can also use [RegExp.test(String)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if the character is valid, and `div.append(char)` in place of `div.html(div.html + char)`.

```
var div = $('#tb');
$(document).on("keypress", function(event) {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (/[0-9+*\/-]/.test(char) === true) {
    div.append(char);
  }
});
```